# Can a PSP play PSOne Classics from PSN (e.g., Final Fantasy VII)?

Tags: ps3, psn, psp, psone-classics

I'm thinking about getting a second hand PSP, the original one with UMD Drive. I just noticed that the PSN Store has many PSOne classics (like Final Fantasy VII and IX), but I wonder if that works on a PSP, or if it needs a Playstation 3, which I don't have?

Comment: (I'd create a psone-classics tag if I had the Rep to do so)

Comment: I really wish they would all be playable on the vita!

Comment: @yx. I'm hoping they'll eventually make that possible...hoping

Comment: @MichaelStum Done!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All PSOne Classics, are playable from both the PSP and the PS3, once purchased from the PSN store.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, all PSOne Classics from the PlayStation Network can be played on all the different versions of the PSP (PSP-1000, PSP-2000, PSP-3000, PSP GO and PSP-E1000).

Just make sure you have downloaded the latest firmware on your system.

From Wikipedia:

> PSOne Classics, launched in North America on December 4, 2006, are
> re-releases of original PlayStation games through emulation on the
> PlayStation Store.
>
> Initially only available for download to the PS3 and playable on the
> PSP. System software version 1.70 for the PS3 allowed PSOne Classics
> to be playable on the PS3.
>
> Eventually the PSP PlayStation Store was added in system software
> version 5.00, allowing the direct download of PSOne Classics to the
> PSP.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you for the inclusion of the PSP Model numbers :) It's Final Fantasy time on my PSP!

Answer (score 1):

I know Final Fantasy VII works on the PSP from the PSN because I'm playing it right now on my PSP!